# Definir id da array() php

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte array()

```
Array
(
    [camposdb] => Array
        (
            [51] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cpf_cnpj
                    [1] => nome_razaosocial
                    [2] => cod_cliente
                    [3] => cod_contrato
                    [4] => mensagem
                    [5] => mensagem
                    [6] => mensagem
                )

            [60] => Array
                (
                    [0] => celular
                    [1] => nome_razaosocial
                    [2] => nome_razaosocial
                    [3] => cod_contrato
                    [4] => mensagem
                    [5] => mensagem
                    [6] => telefone_r_1
                )

        )

)
```

No meu form, seleciono os registros do banco de dados, e coloco os inputs dessa forma: `camposdb[$row_fetch['id']][]` que me trazem o resultado acima.

O que eu preciso fazer é o seguinte...

```
UPDATE tabela SET (cpf_cnpj, nome_razaosocial....) WHERE id = 51
```

.

A pergunta é: Como eu faço para definir que 51 e 60 são ids sendo que eles são dinâmicos?

```
$id = $campodb[0][???]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para buscar as chaves do seu `array` do exemplo acima utilize o [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) para extrair as duas chaves que são os id que precisa:

```
$array = array(
    "camposdb" => array(
        51 => array(
        ),
        60 => array(
        )
    )
);


$id = array_keys($array['camposdb']);
echo $id[0]; //51
echo $id[1]; //60
```

Nesse [exemplo](http://ideone.com/fork/Zqkybr) ilustra bem e soluciona a duvida da busca da chave `array`.

Após edição, para fazer uma busca dinâmica (entendi assim), utilize um `foreach` para pegar as ***chaves*** e depois dentro você consegue pegar as informações de cada chave, onde variável `$key` é o ***id do banco***:

```
foreach(array_keys($array['camposdb']) as $key)
{
    $dados = $array['camposdb'][$key];
}
```

[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/IUvR1u)

Comment: Meus dados vem do $_POST, neste caso o nome dos campos são: camposdb[<? echo $row_fetch['id'];?>][]

Comment: @AndréBaill eu segui o exemplo passado logo acima, e agora eu não entendi como os seus dados vem, então uma edição na sua pergunta ajudaria entender...

Comment: Editei minha questão, talvez compreenda um pouco melhor :)

Comment: Neste caso, eu posso colocar $array = $_POST; ?:

Comment: @AndréBaill para pegar as chaves que podem ser dinâmicas ou não os dois códigos estão ai como exemplo do array que você passou. A função `array_keys` pega as chaves que no caso é **51** e **60** com essas chaves dentro do `array` principal eu faço `array['camposdb'][$key]` que são todas as informações do id selecionado. No exemplo do for a variável dados vai pegar todas as informações de cada id.

Comment: Sim pode. sem problemas @AndréBaill ...

Comment: Ok, deu certinho, era bem isso mesmo que eu precisava @VirgilioNovic, muito obrigado!